# How does it becomes to Id type?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have the following code:

```
import cats._
import cats.Functor

object StudyIt {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val one: Int = 1
    val a = Functor[Id].map(one)(_ + 1)
    println(a)
  }

}
```

As you can see, `map` expects the type of `Id[Int]` but I just past `Int` to `map`, why it is possible?

Answer (score 5):

That's because `Id` is just a type alias, which gets completely inlined at runtime. It looks like this:

```
type Id[A] = A
```

So in essence `Id[Int]` and `Int` are the exact same type.

Comment: What does `completely inlined at runtime` mean?

Comment: It means that everywhere there's an `Id[A]` it will instead turn it into an `A`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `Id[A]` is [literally defined as just `A`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/index.html#Id[A]=A)

```
type Id[A] = A
```

so that `Id[Int]` is just an alias for `Int`.

Here is it, as one of the first definitions (line 34): [Github link](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/package.scala).